# Observer pattern on all instances of class

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I'm trying to learn about the observer pattern, and a case I had thought of is that I want to observe when any instance of a class gets updated, rather than just a singleton. An example I put together is that we have a `DeliverySystem` observer that wants to know when any `Burger` is cooked. We could try to accomplish this with the following:

```js
class Burger {
    static observers: Observer[] = [];

    static addObserver(observer: Observer) {
        Burger.observers = Burger.observers.concat(observer);
    }

    id: number;

    constructor(id: number) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    cook() {
        Burger.observers.forEach(observer => observer.update(this));
    }
}

interface Observer {
    update: (target: any) => void;
}

class DeliverySystem implements Observer {
    update(target: any) {
        console.log("DeliverySystem got pizza " + target.id);
    }

    observe() {
        Burger.addObserver(this);
    }
}


const deliverySystem = new DeliverySystem().observe();
new Burger(12345).cook();
```

This generally works, but I'm not sure how to expand this so that my `DeliverySystem` can observe other foods. If I add a `Hotdog` class, what interface can `Burger` and `Hotdog` both implement that will allow me to avoid each needing to handle their observers independently? I would like to be able to write `Burger` like the following, but I'm not really sure how:

```js
class Burger implements Observable /* <-- what does this look like? */ {
    id: number;

    constructor(id: number) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    cook() {
        updateObservers(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will point you to [Refactoring Guru](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer).

You want your publisher (Observable) to look like this:

```
interface Subscriber {
    update(): void;
}

interface Publisher {
    subscribe(s: Subscriber): void;
    unsubscribe(s: Subscriber): void;
    notifySubscribers(): void;
}
```

You can even go one step further and make them generic if you want.

```
interface Subscriber<C> {
    update(content: C): void;
}

interface Publisher<C> {
    subscribe(s: Subscriber<C>): void;
    unsubscribe(s: Subscriber<C>): void;
    notifySubscribers(): void;
}
```

Comment: I think this falls into the same problem. Following the Refactoring Guru example, I want to extend it so that a `Customer` can subscribe to all `Store`s instead of just a single one.

Comment: So in that case you need to go through each of the `Store` and call `store.subscribe(customer)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the capability to observe all instances then perhaps the Publish Subscribe pattern is more suitable and even more specifically the [Domain Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/domain-events-design-implementation) pattern.

There's two main strategies to dispatch events, but the easiest is to have a PubSub singleton. E.g.

```js
//pub-sub singleton for events
const domainEvents = {
    _subscribers: [],
    publish(event) {
        this._subscribers.forEach(s => s(event));
    },
    subscribe(subscriber) {
        this._subscribers.push(subscriber);
    }
};

class BurgerCooked {
    constructor(burgerId) {
        this.burgerId = burgerId;
        Object.freeze(this);
    }
}

class Burger {
    constructor(id) {
       this._id = id;
       this._cooked = false;
    }
    
    get id() { return this._id }
    get cooked() { return this._cooked }
    cook() {
        if (this.cooked) {
           throw new Error('already cooked');
        }
        this._cooked = true;
        domainEvents.publish(new BurgerCooked(this.id));
    }
}

domainEvents.subscribe(e => {
   if (e instanceof BurgerCooked) {
       console.log(`${e.burgerId} is cooked!`);
   }
});

const b1 = new Burger('b1');
const b2 = new Burger('b2');

b1.cook();
b2.cook();
```

Usually domain events won't carry direct aggregate (e.g. `Burger`) references to facilitate their serialization & storage and ensure they are immutable. There's usually a [`Repository`](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) that mimics an in-memory collection and allows to retrieve aggregate instances by id.